# In jqGrid's textarea where is the Scroll Bar?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid-php

I want to know how to display the scroll bar in jqgrid.

i use the jqgrid for display some data with textarea

```
     colModel:[
   {name:'mob_id',index:'mob_id', editable:false,width:30},
   {name:'cse_id',index:'cse_id', editable:true, edittype:'text',width:30},
   {name:'sub_id',index:'sub_id',edittype:'text',editable:true,width:30},
   {name:'avg_user_rating',index:'avg_user_rating',editable:true,edittype:'textarea',editoptions:{rows:'3',cols:'20'},width:30}]
```

the textarea is display but there is no scroll bar.

thanks in advance

Comment: When you type the content and fill the viewable area of the textarea then you did not view any Scroll Bar. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
  white-space: normal !important;
  height:auto;
  vertical-align:text-top;
  padding-top:2px;
}
```

inside your css file. it should show the entire content. if you want scrollbar, just set the height to a fixed number of pixels i think.